# Welcome to Wales sign near Chester

Tags: where-on-earth, england, road-signs, wales

Me and the Mrs like getting pictures next to signs, got quite a few states in America, only got welcome to Scotland in the UK.

We are staying in Chester in a couple of weeks and wondered if anyone knew where a 'Welcome to Wales' sign is near Chester, had a quick look on google maps but its mostly urban areas with no indication of the border.

Needs to be somewhere no more than 30 mins drive away and somewhere you can park up and get out so not a motorway.

If it has 'Welcome to England' of the other side of the road that would be great too, need to get that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here's one](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@53.1992176,-2.9387334,3a,75y,306.92h,84.51t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1szE96VHGW0Z20Iy9Qfp6GVg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656), on Sealand Road at the junction with Western Avenue to the west of Chester itself. A small "England - Cheshire" sign also exists on the other side. In terms of parking I imagine you could probably get away with waiting in that access drive to the field for a couple of minutes unless the farmer's around! If you're less lazy and more cautious it looks like residential areas are very close by which have on-street parking with no permit system.

It also looks to be reasonably walkable from Chester itself (about a 45-50 minute walk from the city centre), if you fancy a good stroll.

The next place that looks to have a good sign (there might be one on Wrexham Road, the B5445, but frustratingly Google Street View images around the border seem to be missing) is [Bridge Street in the village of Holt](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@53.0826781,-2.8804118,3a,75y,163.09h,92.88t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s_VVlNa9tSyGNGIRjegAyiw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656), about 25 minutes' drive from Chester according to Google. It has a rather quaint-looking bridge over the River Dee (where the actual border is located), and a "Cheshire - England" sign on the other end of the bridge (the bridge itself is too narrow for signs).

Comment: There are also buses that serve the area, if you are without a car. I have visited friends in Saltney but I do not remember signs. It is just the next sub-urb.

Comment: That will do thanks :) @Willeke will have my car, probably do it before I go home

Comment: As a comment, in general, such signs tend to only be present on the more important roads, as the council don't want to go to the expense of providing signs for every back road. Though I'm sure there are exceptions so if you wanted a quieter road it might well be possible to find one. I actually found a quiet road with another "England - Cheshire" sign but no Wales one!

Comment: @BritishSam just found another place not *too* far away which you might prefer as it's more quaint/photogenic...

Comment: @Muzer looks a lot nicer there, cheers